# Execute only second package observer

Tags: event-observer, ce-1.9.0.1, package, dependency

I have two packages installed in magento.
First,`Package1_Test1`
second,`Package2_Test2`.
I have created one observer in `Package1_Test1`

path: **community/Package1/Test1/etc/config.xml**

```
<sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
                <observers>
                    <package1_test1_identifier>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>package1_test1/observer</class>
                        <method>salesConvertQuoteItemToOrderItem</method>
                    </package1_test1_identifier>
                </observers>
</sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
```

In `Package2_Test2`,I have created one observer

path: **community/Package2/Test2/etc/config.xml**

```
<sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
                <observers>
                    <package2_test2_identifier>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>package2_test2/observer</class>
                        <method>salesConvertQuoteItemToOrderItem</method>
                    </package2_test2_identifier>
                </observers>
</sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
```

It means that I have created same `sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item` observer in both `packages` so my question is I want to run only second `Package2_Test2` package observer rather then `Package1_Test1`.

Any dependency will work between two packages ?

Please help me,What I have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the observer on package1_test1 by placing code as below into package1_test2

Basically, you disable the observer in package1_test1

```
<events>
    <sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
       <observers>
          <package1_test1_identifier>
              <type>disabled</type>
          </package1_test1_identifier>
       </observers>
    </sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
</events>
```

If you want to use the code in package1_test1, you can simply extend  (not rewrite) package1_test1 class from package1_test2, and then call it as a parent class.